# How to perform a specific buffer overflow bypassing a length check

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, strlen

I'm trying to perform a bufferoverflow so that a variable (type) has a specific value in it. I struggle with the strlen & check for my input.

I tried using something like: 'AAAAA\x00AAA...A\x00\xbc\xd4\xb9' for tricking the strlen check that my input is just 5 A's long. But something strips my \x00 always with the message:

-bash: Warnung: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

So i went to make a way bigger input and have an Integer overflow so that the short where the length is saved to is too big and gets below 32700... But that didnt seem to work either.

My inputs are constructed as follow:

```
./challenge `python -c "print 'A'*30000 + '\x00' + 'A'*10000" + '\xXX\xXX\xXX\xXX'`
```

(for \xXX my desired inputs)

or

```
./challenge `python programm.py`
```

I am also using gdb for the analysis of the memory. But i cant find the correct way to use it...

The code for my task is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int type = 0xdeadbeef;
    char buf[32700];
    short len;

    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;

    len = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (len > 32700) {
        printf("Too long\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    if (type == 0x00b1c2d3) {
        printf("Success\n");
    } else {
        printf("Try again\n");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Any other ideas (or a 'solution') for this problem? I am trying so hard now since days. Also i didn't have anything todo with C (especially memory analysis, gdb and all of that) for years, so it's extra hard for me to understand some things.

Comment: You are trying to exploit the wrong thing. Planting 0s in the middle of the string will not help you.

Comment: @TomKarzes there's more than that to it. The program is buggy but this is not the only bug. The assignment is to find and exploit these bugs to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Tom Karzes my thought for inserting the \x00 was it is a null Byte, so the strlen goes to that and thinks the string is at its end. Resulting in a wrong/shorter length.

Comment: @n.m. yes, it is a assignment from my University to get started with vulnerabilities and exploits. Any idea what would help me?

Comment: `strcpy` will stop at the first 0 byte just like `strlen`

Comment: Notice that `len` is of type short while `strlen` will return a value with type `size_t` so what happens if you supply a string the is 32,768  (0x8000) bytes long?  What value winds up in `len`?  (opps, user3896931 posed the answer while testing this comment)

Comment: Someone has unfortunately done all your homework for you. In the future, you should try to compile the code with the highest warning level possible (say clang -Weverything; with gcc you need to pass many -W options). Every warning is a potential attack vector (though not all vectors can be caught this way).

Comment: @n.m. The homework is to make the output "success". The code has been compiled before. I have the program and the source code, i did nothing on that.

Comment: You should compile it not to run it but to see the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in the code is that the length `len`, which is calculated using `strlen()`, is a `short`.  This means it's a 16-bit value.  Since `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is a 64-bit value on my x86_64 system, only the bottom 16 bits will be stored in the `len` variable.

So, on first glance you can submit anything longer than 65,535 bytes, overflow that `short int`, and store just the lower 16-bits.  But there's another issue to note.  The `len` variable is a *signed* short integer.  This means that it stores values from `[-32768,32767]`, whereas a `size_t` is an unsigned value.  So when `strlen()` returns its value, lengths that have the highest bit set (anything over 32,767 bytes) will become negative numbers.

Here's an example `gdb` session illustrating this:

```
(gdb) break 22
Breakpoint 1 at 0x829: file challenge.c, line 22.
(gdb) run `ruby -e 'print("A"*32768)'`
Starting program: /home/josh/foo/challenge `ruby -e 'print("A"*32768)'`

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffff6338) at challenge.c:22
22          if (type == 0x00b1c2d3) {
(gdb) p len
$1 = -32768
(gdb) x/64bx $rsp
0x7ffffffee260: 0x38    0x63    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7ffffffee268: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7ffffffee270: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7ffffffee278: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x80    0xef    0xbe    0xad    0xde
0x7ffffffee280: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7ffffffee288: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7ffffffee290: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7ffffffee298: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
(gdb)
```

See how the bytes at `0x7ffffffee27a` are `0x00 0x80`?  That's -32768 to a `short int`, so the length is perceived to be negative (well under 32,700!).

I also included some extra info in the memory dump there, so you can see that the `type` field immediately succeeds the `len` field in memory, followed finally by the `buf` array (which contains my 32768 `A`s!).  Note that only certain lengths of input will work -- those that appear negative, or overflow to a value less than 32,700 when truncated to 16 bits.

This doesn't solve the entire challenge, but at least should give you a good start to understanding what you can control.  Note also that there is data above the `buf` array, such as where `rbp` points, your saved return pointer, etc.  Depending on how you are compiling this (e.g., with or without stack canaries, etc.), there might be some more things for you to solve along the way.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!! Thats really a good explanation (although i still dont have a idea how i can overflow the type variable, but i guess i have to try a bit more) :)

Comment: You won't be able to "overflow" the type variable, though I suppose some compilers might arrange the variables on the stack differently.  What you can do, though, is control execution and change it with a shellcode, perhaps.